# Why does MSVC STL use this way to have two objects share the same cache line?

Tags: c++, caching, stl, x86-64

Here is part of [the code](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/any) for `std::any` in MSVC STL:

```
class any {
    // ...
    struct _Small_storage_t {
        unsigned char _Data[_Any_small_space_size];
        const _Any_small_RTTI* _RTTI;
    };
    static_assert(sizeof(_Small_storage_t) == _Any_trivial_space_size);

    struct _Big_storage_t {
        // Pad so that _Ptr and _RTTI might share _TypeData's cache line
        unsigned char _Padding[_Any_small_space_size - sizeof(void*)];
        void* _Ptr;
        const _Any_big_RTTI* _RTTI;
    };
    static_assert(sizeof(_Big_storage_t) == _Any_trivial_space_size);

    struct _Storage_t {
        union {
            unsigned char _TrivialData[_Any_trivial_space_size];
            _Small_storage_t _SmallStorage;
            _Big_storage_t _BigStorage;
        };
        uintptr_t _TypeData;
    };
    static_assert(sizeof(_Storage_t) == _Any_trivial_space_size + sizeof(void*));
    static_assert(is_standard_layout_v<_Storage_t>);

    union {
        _Storage_t _Storage{};
        max_align_t _Dummy;
    };
};
```

We can see that the main storage part is `_Storage_t`, which will be `_Small_storage_t`, `_Big_storage_t` or just `unsigned char` array according to the type of the object saved in `std::any`.

I can't understand the meaning of the comments in `_Big_storage_t`:

```
// Pad so that _Ptr and _RTTI might share _TypeData's cache line
unsigned char _Padding[_Any_small_space_size - sizeof(void*)];
```

And on my platform, the values of some parameters are:

```
sizeof(void*);  // 8 bytes
constexpr int _Small_object_num_ptrs = 6 + 16 / sizeof(void*); // 8
constexpr size_t _Any_small_space_size = (_Small_object_num_ptrs - 2) * sizeof(void*); // 48
constexpr size_t _Any_trivial_space_size = (_Small_object_num_ptrs - 1) * sizeof(void*); // 56
sizeof(_Small_storage_t);  // 56 bytes
sizeof(_Big_storage_t);    // 56 bytes
```

My questions are

1. Why does `_Padding` allow `_Ptr` and `_RTTI` to share cache lines with `_TypeData`?
2. What are the benefits of doing this (sharing cache line)?

Comment: I think the idea is to have `_Ptr` and `_RTTI` close to `_TypeData`. Remember this is a union where `_Big_storage_t`, without padding, is significantly smaller than the other items. I think the alignment imposed on `any` is only 16B (or even 8B) so the `_Storage` structure could be anywhere in the 64B cache line. By having those fields one next to the other in memory they increase the chance they share the same cache line even in case `_Storage` crosses a line boundary. Having all of them in the same cache line increase performance by not having to fetch and waste a line just to read a pointer